# Only Ideal in group G is G itself.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group. Then, since G is a semigroup also, there is a possibility that some subset of G is an ideal. Prove that the only ideal in G is G itself.

I understand that you would need to show that if an ideal existed as a subset of G, that in turn, G is a subset of the ideal. I'm not sure how to rigorously show this.

Comment: Wouldn't you just observe that for $g\in I$, $g^{-1}g=1\in I$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be a (non-empty) ideal in $G$.  Given $a \in S$, we must have $e=aa^{-1} \in S$.  Now that $e \in S$, we have $g \in S$ for all $g \in G$:  $g = ge$.  Hence $S=G$.